# Understanding the gradient of the social cost curve in a market failure/ negative externalities diagram

Tags: supply-and-demand, market-failure

[image: Market Failure (negative externalities diagram]

Why does the social cost supply curve in a negative externalities diagram have a steeper gradient than the private cost to firms?

I assumed it should only be shifted upwards as the negative social costs are directly proportional to the production quantity?

Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It simply depends on the shape of the marginal external damages. If the **total** damages are linear in output, then the **marginal** damages are constant, and the gradient of the marginal social cost is the same as that of the marginal private cost.

If the **total** damages are quadratic (or some other form with increasing *marginal* damages), the marginal social cost has a steeper slope than the marginal private cost.

In a simple example: if the marginal *private* costs are $MPC(Q)=70+2Q$, where $Q$ is quantity produced and *total* damages are $D(Q)=50Q$, then marginal external damages are $MED=50$ and the marginal social costs of production would be:

$MSC=MPC+MED=70+2Q+50=120+2Q$

If in contrast the damage function would be $D(Q)=50Q+2Q^2$, then marginal external damages would be $MED=50+4Q$ and the marginal social costs of production:

$MSC=MPC+MED=120+6Q$

As you can see the latter has a steeper slope than the original MPC, whereas the former does not.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation!